# Using arguments for tikz style in standaloneframe not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, standalone

For creating TikZ images for beamer presentations I use the `standalone`package and standalone frame.

Now I reallized that if I try to define tikz style with an argument (`#1`) locally at the tikz picture I get an error while, if it is defined in the document header (or before `\begin{standaloneframe}` everything is fine.

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\tikzset{text/.style = {draw= #1, fill = #1!10}} % Setting the style here works fine

\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}

\begin{tikzpicture}% [text/.style = {draw= #1, fill = #1!10}] % <-- if you uncomment this you get an error

    \draw[text=red] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);   
    \draw[text=green] (4, 0) rectangle (6,3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

Is this a bug in the `standalone` package or are I am doing something wrong? Is there a workaround?

Comment: If you use four (!) `#` it works: `\begin{tikzpicture}[text/.style = {draw= ####1, fill = ####1!10}]`.

Comment: Add the `[fragile]` option to `standaloneframe` just like in normal `beamer` when things get strange.

Comment: In a normal `beamer` document you also need four: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}[text/.style = {draw= ####1, fill = ####1!10}] 

    \draw[text=red] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);   
    \draw[text=green] (4, 0) rectangle (6,3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}`, or, `fragile` as @daleif says. This is because of the way `beamer` works.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your answers. What is the difference between `#1` and `####1`?